# Polearm, reach homebrew weapon for Kensei Monk balance

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew, homebrew-review

I will be running a campaign and one of my players wants to play specifically a Kensei Monk with a polearm weapon that has reach and is not heavy or special, so he can use it as kensei weapon. He wants to play variant human with the sentinel and polearm master feats. At level one I presume he would pick one of those. To balance a weapon for him I read [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113874/how-can-i-use-a-polearm-with-reach-as-a-monk-kensei-weapon) and they say it would be balanced with either a 1d6 long quarterstaff or 1d8 long spear. But it seems to me that the combinations with feats is still too strong especially with the sentinel feat at level 1. I wanted to allow either a 1d6 weapon with any starting feat, or a 1d8 weapon with the condition that the first feat cannot be sentinel. My reasoning is that the character would have too much damage and too good control at level 1. Reducing the movement speed to 0 on a wrong move seems very strong.

So I see two possible solutions:

1. The answer to the linked question applies to this one regardless of
   feats, in which case sorry to bother.
2. My reasoning would be a better balance and can be applied.

**Which of the two proposed solutions is correct?**

Let me know if any more information is necessary.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What's the actual question here? Please note that we are not a discussion forum. While we do allow 'homebrew review' type questions they, for one have to have an actual question, and two, need to state what you are trying to accomplish with the homebrew. As a Q&A site we don't do discussion. See [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/14878)

Comment: Which of the three proposed solutions is correct? But I don't want to set this up for a frame challenge in case I am missing something obvious. But I like frame challenges nonetheless.

Comment: It shouldn't really be a homebrew review, I think. I'm not concerned about the weapon in general, just about the particular case I present.

Comment: Removed the third general solution to avoid idea generation problem.

Comment: So, why do you want to allow this? The way I read this, the player just wants an advantage, essentially trying to game the system. I guess this kinda comes under your first solution, but why have you not just said "no, that's not how that works and I don't think allowing it would be balanced"?

Comment: I did not think about not allowing it. I guess it just escaped my mind. Would that be the correct answer here? I guess I have to ask more questions to the player about why they want this. I always try to give my players the opportunity to play the character they want to play. But maybe this change is not for thematic purposes and is for mechanic purposes alone. Thank you for the different point of view!

Comment: What about a spear does not work for this weapon: lack of reach?  The reason that I ask is that the Errata for the PHB (2018) included spears as able to use the polearm mastery feat.

Comment: After talking to the player the reach seems to be the issue, yes. He says it's for having a monk that will fight by keeping the enemies at a distance and if they get too close pummel them. I think I will just say no.